# Output to string instead of wofstream

Tags: c++, string, wstring, wofstream

For the following code, is it possible to output the result to a string instead of wofstream? Thanks you!

```
wstring w = L"test";
std::wofstream ofs("test.txt");
std::locale utf8_locale(std::locale(), new boost::archive::detail::utf8_codecvt_facet());
ofs.imbue(utf8_locale);
std::copy(w.begin(),w.end(),
    std::ostream_iterator<wchar_t, wchar_t>(ofs));
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream

Comment: Hi Chris, could you elaborate it further with some code? I am not familiar with C++

Comment: `std::wostringstream` is derived from the same class as `std::wofstream`, so replacing just the type of variable used should still be compatible with the other functions you use. Stringstreams maintain a string rather than a file, though (accessed via `str()`), which should fulfill your needs.

Comment: Like std::string output = woss.str();? Sorry for the dumb question again, how do you know wostringstream and wofstream are derived from a same class?

Comment: I understand now. This is also helpful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io

Comment: Very. If you wanted a direct reference, the standard would be the place to look. It's a bit easier to explain with pictures, though :) Just because I can, I found this in § 27.3/5: `The class template specialization basic_ostream<charT,traits> serves as a base class for class templates
basic_ostringstream and basic_ofstream.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output string streams are a C++ feature that behave similarly to output file streams in the sense that they both inherit from `std::ostream`, meaning that you can use mostly the same functions in both. However, string streams operate on a string rather than a file.

What this means for you is that all you need to do (as you haven't used any `wofstream`-specific functions) is change the type of `ofs` to a string stream:

```
#include <sstream>
std::wostringstream oss;
```

Now I couldn't get the locale stuff building (I haven't used those as of yet), but commenting them did indeed produce correct results ([see this test](http://liveworkspace.org/code/dbaabe6b5ef07dd46cf320e74bba33c1)). As you can see, you can access the string via the string stream's `str()` function.

Comment: Right. But actually str() returns a wstring, not a string... Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @echo, With a bit of snooping, you'll find that both `std::ostringstream` and `std::wostringstream` are actually the same basic class, but with a different template argument. The former's is `char` and the latter's is `wchar_t`. The `str()` function returns a `std::basic_string<CharT>`, where `CharT` is the template argument. This basically evaluates to a `std::string` or `std::wstring` respectively, with the exact same code. If you wanted the whole mess to use your own char type, you could say `std::basic_ostringstream<YourType>` to have no code changes produce correct types.